# changing listbox items order

Tags: c++, c++builder

I have a ListBox with font library in it. I need to change order of 2 items by clicking my 'Edit' button, first font with last font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to swap two items with each other, you can use the `Exchange()` method:

```
if (ListBox1->Items->Count > 1)
    ListBox1->Items->Exchange(0, ListBox1->Items->Count-1);
```